# Deploying asp.net Web Service referencing web service

Tags: asp.net, web-services, deployment, web-deployment

I've a asp.net web solution which references a web service from another web site (also in our development environment). I want to know if I need to change the address of the web service (from production server) when deploying to production and how or if it is not necessary to make any changes?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First off, make sure the WebService is set to Dynamic.

Then I suggest you put the URI in your web.config file as follows:

```
<appSettings>
    <add key="WebServiceUri" value="http://example.com/service.asmx"/>
</appSettings>
```

When you then instantiate the WebService, do the following:

```
WebService service = new WebService();
service.Uri = ConfigurationSettings.AppSettings["WebServiceUri"];
```

The WebService will now use that URI in every WebService request it makes.

Answer (score 0):

I'd say put the actual URL of the webservice in the appSettings part of your web.config, then use that at runtime.

Comment: exactly but I want to know how?